# pandas dataframe look ahead value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What's the best way to do this with pandas dataframe? I want to loop through a dataframe, and compute the difference between the current value and the next value which is different than the current value.
For example:
[13, 13, 13, 14, 13, 12]
will create a new column with this
[-1, -1, -1, 1, 1]

Comment: Why is there a -1 for 12 when there is no value after 12?

Comment: @Psidom you are right, I corrected it. the last one can be Nan or anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about use `diff` to calculate the difference and then back fill 0 with the next non zero value:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"S": [13, 13, 13, 14, 13, 12]})

df.S.diff(-1).replace(0, np.nan).bfill()  # replace zero with nan and apply back fill.

# 0    -1
# 1    -1
# 2    -1
# 3     1
# 4     1
# 5   NaN
# Name: S, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I am figuring out what you doing, but wow this is really cool. Thanks.

Comment: what if i want to do the old fashion way with 2 loops. How do I write that 2 loops. I just want to know the pandas dataframe syntax, not the optimization of the actual logic

Comment: btw this is really smart